# How to use spark_read_avro from sparklyr R package?

Tags: r, databricks, avro, sparklyr, spark-avro

I'm using:
R version 4.1.1
sparklyr version ‘1.7.2’

I'm connected to my databricks cluster with databricks-connect and trying to read an avro file using the following code:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

sc <- spark_connect(
  method = "databricks", 
  spark_home = "my_spark_home_path",
  version = "3.1.1",
  packages = c("avro")
  )

df_path = "s3a://my_s3_path"
df = spark_read_avro(sc, path = df_path, memory = FALSE)
```

I also tried with explicitly adding the package:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

sc <- spark_connect(
  method = "databricks", 
  spark_home = "my_spark_home_path",
  version = "3.1.1",
  packages = "org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.1.1"
  ) 

df_path = "s3a://my_s3_path"
df = spark_read_avro(sc, path = df_path, memory = FALSE)
```

The spark connection is working, I can read parquet files normally, but when reading the avro file I always get:

```
Error in validate_spark_avro_pkg_version(sc) : 
  Avro support must be enabled with `spark_connect(..., version = <version>, packages = c("avro", <other package(s)>), ...)`  or by explicitly including 'org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.1.1-SNAPSHOT' for Spark version 3.1.1-SNAPSHOT in list of packages
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround using *sparkavro* package:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
library(sparkavro)

sc <- spark_connect(
  method = "databricks", 
  spark_home = "my_spark_home_path") 

df_path = "s3a://my_s3_path"
df = spark_read_avro(
   sc, 
   path = df_path, 
   name = "my_table_name", 
   memory = FALSE)
```